# Можно ли циклом создать n переменных? Преобразование строки в переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x

Меня интересует возможно ли создать переменные х1, х2 и т.д. с помощью цикла, например, вот так:

```
i = 1
while i < 5:
  "x" + str(i) = i*i #тут не работает, потому что строкам нельзя придавать значение int
print(x1) # x1 = 1
print(x2) # x2 = 4
...
print(x5) # x5 = 25
```

И можно в 3 строке преобразовать строки "xi" в переменную xi?

Comment: Чем вам массивы не угодили ?

Comment: для связки аналогичного: [Как динамически создать переменную, в названии которой может содержаться значение другой переменной?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/959006/178576)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так вы создадите переменные:

```
i = 1

while i <= 5:
    exec("x{} = {}".format(i, i * i))
    i += 1

print(x1) # x1 = 1
print(x2) # x2 = 4
print(x3) # x3 = 9
print(x4) # x4 = 16
print(x5) # x5 = 25
```

Еще можно использовать `locals()` или `globals()`:

```
while i <= 5:
    locals()['x' + str(i)] = i * i
    # Или:
    globals()['x' + str(i)] = i * i
    i += 1
```

---

**PS.** мне кажется, в подобных вычислениях лучше использовать коллекции (`list`, `dict`, ...), чем `exec`, `locals` или `globals`

Answer (score 6):

Я бы в вашем случае использовал словарь:

```
x = {i:i**2 for i in range(1,6)}

print(x)
# {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25}

print(x[3])
# 9
```