# Как динамически создать переменную

Tags: python, python-faq

Как динамически создать переменную, в названии которой может содержаться значение другой переменной?

Например, нужно создать переменную следующим образом (псевдокод):

```
Имя_%номер-пользователя% = значение
```

Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Динамическое создание переменных сложно поддерживать. И это может быть не безопасно.

Вы можете использовать словари. Словари - это хранилища ключей и значений.

```
>>> dct = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
>>> dct
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>> dct["y"]
```

Можно так же использовать имена ключей как переменные

```
>>> x = "spam"
>>> z = {x: "eggs"}
>>> z["spam"]
'eggs'
```

Для случаев, когда вы думаете о чем-то вроде

```
var1 = 'foo'
var2 = 'bar'
var3 = 'baz'
...
```

Список может быть более подходящим, чем словарь, особенно если вам нужна числовая нумерация. Список - упорядоченная последовательность объектов с целочисленными индексами:

```
l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
print(l[1])           # prints bar, because indices start at 0
l.append('potatoes')  # l is now ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'potatoes']
```

Списки могут быть более удобны, чем словари с целыми ключами. Например добавлять и удалять элементы так удобнее.

Answer (score 12):

Например, так:

```
import os

uid = os.getuid()
print(uid)  # 1000

try:
   print(name_1000)
except NameError as e:
   print(e)  # name 'name_1000' is not defined

locals()[f'name_{uid}'] = 42

print(name_1000)  # 42
```

Но надо помнить, что динамическое создание переменных - это очень плохая практика. Скорее всего, задуманное надо реализовывать через ассоциативные структуры данных (словарь, например).

В зависимости от задачи, переменная может быть создана не только в локальной, но и в глобальной области видимости с использованием функции `globals`.

Comment: Или `globals()[...] = ...`

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, обновил ответ