# Как задать кнопки в цикле?

Tags: python, tkinter

в цикле идет наполнение окна: (button - любое, не одинаковое количество)
Как правильно заполнить цикл, чтобы кнопок было несколько?

```
    for i in dict_:
        elif i['object'] == 'button':
            self.btn = AButton(parent, isize_)
            self.btn.setStyleSheet(bgcolor_, bghcolor_)
            self.btn.setImage(i['icon'])
            self.btn.setCommand()
            self.btn.show()
```

Прочитал статью по предложенной [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959006/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) .
Ответа на свой вопрос не получил, т.к.:
мне не нужно создавать список типа `'строка'`, мне нужно обозначить несколько элементов типа `'объект'` каждого со своим наименованием, а именно `AButton(parent, isize_)`, который написан вручную с помощью tkinter - Canvas.

т.е.:

```
self.btn1 = AButton(parent, isize_)
...
self.btn2 = AButton(parent, isize_)
...
```

Благодаря insolor (см. комментарии), ответом является следующее:

```
    nb = 0; self.btn = []
    
    for i in dict_:
        if i['name'] == 'label':
            .....

        elif i['name'][:-1] == 'button':
            b = AButton(parent, isize_)
            self.btn.append(b)
            self.btn[nb].setStyleSheet(bgcolor_, bghcolor_)
            self.btn[nb].setImage(i['icon'])
            self.btn[nb].setCommand()
            self.btn[nb].show()
            nb=+1
```

Comment: Вам нужно не меняющееся имя переменной, а обычный список кнопок.

Comment: `Ответа на свой вопрос не получил, т.к.: мне не нужно создавать список типа 'строка'` - без разницы, от типа объекта суть не меняется. Суть в том, что нужно использовать список вместо нумерованных имен переменных. Создаете пустой список `self.btn = []`, потом в цикле добавляете в него элементы: `b = AButton(parent, isize_)` `self.btn.append(b)`

Comment: insolor, спасибо, я думал в этом же направлении, но где-то была ошибка и не срабатывало.