# Суммирование чисел с остановкой на определенной цифре

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Не получается найти решение. 
Есть некий массив чисел:

```
a=[1,2,3,2,1,5,0,3,2,4,1,0,4,7,3,2]
```

и переменные:

```
c=0
d=0
e=0
```

Нужно, чтобы все числа массива **`a`** суммировались, но при цифре **`0`** суммирование останавливалось. Т.е массив `а`, суммировать 1+2+3+2+1+5, и эту сумму записать в переменную `с`, и далее заново суммировать числа 3+2+4+1, сумма записать в переменную `d` и 4+7+3+2 записать в переменную `e`.

Пытаюсь сделать суммирование через

```
for x in a:
   x+=x
```

Но не знаю, как остановить суммирование на нуле и записать в разные переменные.

Подскажите, плиз.

Comment: вы понимаете, что в своем цикле вы поочередно читаете переменную `x` из списка `a` каждый раз при каждой итерации? и потом ее к самой себе прибавляете? так делать _нельзя_.

Comment: Так делать можно. Просто бесполезно. :)

Comment: У Вас всегда будут 2 нуля в списке? Если нет, то для хранения результатов лучше использовать что-нибудь типа списка или словаря

Comment: Игорь, если ответы были полезны, их можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Ответ, который полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь функционалом модуля itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby
a=[1,2,3,2,1,5,0,3,2,4,1,0,4,7,3,2]

res = []
for i, g in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x!=0):
    if i:
        res.append(sum(g))

print(res)
```

> [14, 10, 16]

Comment: Но где же запись в с, d, e требуемая по заданию?

Comment: @Сергей ну да, записать данные из списка в переменную - это нужно быть семи пядей во лбу. А если нолей в списке окажется больше или меньше?

Comment: Это да, но красиво было бы как-то переменные менять по очереди в зависимости от номера нуля по порядку.

Comment: @Сергей это прагматично неверный подход: создавать отдельные переменные, проверять их количество, менять названия переменных в зависимости от группы - для чего? есть железный список, длина которого известна. к элементом которого можно обращаться по индексу. вот это - прагматически верный подход.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Вертелась в голове  идея генерации имен переменных по алфавиту после каждого ноля. Тогда "если нолей в списке окажется больше или меньше" будет вообще не страшно. Но да, если и сделать, для этой конкретной  задачи будет слишком громоздко.

Comment: @Сергей, для вас: `c, d, e = res`.

Comment: Можно без создания промежуточного списка: `c, d, e = (sum(g) for k, g in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x != 0) if k)`

Comment: И ещё короче: `c, d, e = (sum(g) for k, g in groupby(a, key=bool) if k)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, прям вот просится в ответ. Прекрасное решение. Не для уровня ТС, но все же

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да, спасибо, это полезно, но я имел в виду динамическое создание переменных.  Сделать что-то вроде `locals()[f'{chr(99+i)}'] += x`, где `i` сначала равно 0, а далее увеличивается с каждым 0. Но не работает, хоть писали на SO, что должно. Впрочем, динамическое создание переменных не рекомендую всё равно, так что забросил я это.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, вот ссылка:<https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959006/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8>, если интересно. Не работает их пример, даже с `os.getpid()`

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 4, 7, 3, 2]
index = 0
temp_list = [0] * 3

for ele in a:
    if not ele:
        index += 1
    temp_list[index] += ele

c, d, e = temp_list
```

Comment: Да, хороший вариант, это убирает множественное ветвление и одновременно не сложно.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from itertools import takewhile

a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 4, 7, 3, 2]

def take_sum_list(value_list: list):
    while value_list:
        part = list(takewhile(lambda s: s != 0, value_list))
        value_list = value_list[len(part) + 1:]
        yield sum(part)

print(
    list(take_sum_list(a))
)

# Если уверены в количестве значений
a, b, c = take_sum_list(a)
print(
    f'{a = }',
    f'{b = }',
    f'{c = }',
    sep='\n'
)
```

output

```
[14, 10, 16]
a = 14
b = 10
c = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Грубовато, но работает ниже (ещё и не сразу заработало:-(). Хочется чего-то поизящнее, конечно.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 4, 7, 3, 2]
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
i = 0
while a[i]:
    c += a[i]
    i += 1
i += 1
while a[i]:
    d += a[i]
    i += 1
i += 1
while i < len(a):
    e += a[i]
    i += 1
print(c, d, e)
```

Вот чуть короче, но тоже не идеал:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 4, 7, 3, 2]
c, d, e, i = 0, 0, 0, 0
for x in a:
    if not x:
        i += 1
    elif i == 0:
        c += x
    elif i == 1:
        d += x
    else:
        e += x
print(c, d, e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто:

```py
a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,0,3,2,4,1,0,4,7,3,2]
res = [0]
for v in a:
    if v:
        res[-1] += v
    else:
        res.append(0)
c, d, e, *f, = res
print(c,d,e)
```

Вывод:

```
14 10 16
```