# Автомат. Название/создание переменных

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемой, нужно создать файл в windows, с помощью цикла, т.е. чтобы возможно было создавать бесконечное(в пределах памяти в ПК) количество переменных и файлов. Допустим, пример:

```
while True:
    s = input()
    str(s)
    if s == 'end':
        quit()
    else:
        a = s
        print(a)
```

Нужно, чтобы переменная a не менялась, а сохранялись и создавались новые. Например:

```
print(a, a344, sep=', ')
    H, T
```

В какой то мере нужно, чтобы переменные назывались произвольно, чтобы не надо было создавать их по мере прохождения кода. Ведь нельзя просто назвать переменную:

```
Random.choice(alphabet)
```

Также и с файлами в windows.
Надеюсь, вы поняли мою мысль.

Comment: Не понял мысль. Зачем вам создавать новые переменные? Как вы их хотите использовать? Массив/список не годится?

Comment: С теми же  файлами в windows не пройдёт такое,  да и если потом потребуется вызывать по отдельности, и выполнять всякие действия с этими переменными, такое не пройдёт, да и эту прогу я написал для примера.

Comment: @disscorier для хранения файлов (или открытых файлов, или что вам там нужно) не нужны уникальные имена переменных, можно один список или словарь. С уникальными именами переменных такая проблема - как вы потом найдете все эти уникальные переменные? В список имена их будете складывать? А почему сразу сами файлы сразу в список не складывать?

Comment: Если хотите имена делать по типу буквы+номер, то с тем же успехом, но намного более удобно использовать именно список, а не извращаться с созданием переменных.

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/959006/178576)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужны новые переменные в памяти можно использовать функцию `exec`, для примера `exec(f'{variable_name}={value}')`

Для файлов подойдёт функция `open` -> `f = open(f"{filename}", "a")`