# Как можно сократить данный код? (ЯП Python)

Tags: python, рефакторинг

Я пробовал сократить через цикл, но не понял, как можно присвоить имена item_1, item_2, и так далее. Буду благодарен за помощь, не думаю, что для сообщества сократить этот код будет сложно

```
item_1 = InlineQueryResultArticle(
    id=result_id,
    title=url_list[0],
    input_message_content=input_content
    )
item_2 = InlineQueryResultArticle(
    id=result_id,
    title=url_list[l],
    input_message_content=input_content
    )
item_3 = InlineQueryResultArticle(
    id=result_id,
    title=url_list[2],
    input_message_content=input_content
    )
item_4 = InlineQueryResultArticle(
    id=result_id,
    title=url_list[3],    
    input_message_content=input_content
    )
item_5 = InlineQueryResultArticle(
    id=result_id,
    title=url_list[4],
    input_message_content=input_content
```

Comment: но правильнее, конечно, использовать массив.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: >meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/… 
заменил фото на текст

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще массив

[new] Например:

```
items = []

for i in range(5):
    items.append(InlineQueryResultArticle(
        id=result_id,
        title=url_list[i],
        input_message_content=input_content
    ))
```

Comment: Какая именно ошибка? Я пишу с телефона

Comment: @Euaek вы в коде пытаетесь менять значения пустого списка (длины 0), обращаясь при этом к индексу `i+1`

Comment: А точно, убери его тогда

Comment: @Euaek, почему вы обращаетесь на ты к человеку, который к вам обращается прилично на вы?

Comment: Я уже пробовал так делать, но этот способ не создает переменные item1, item2 и другие, а мне как раз нужны именно переменные, чтобы использовать их в выдаче результатов в InlineQuery в aiogram

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959006/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e

Comment: Если честно, это плохая идея, лучше массив, так что выше вопрос есть

Comment: @max, вам не нужны отдельные переменные. Если у вас в коде вдруг появляются нумерованные переменные, значит нужно этот код выбросить и переписать со списком вместо отдельных переменных, т.е. в вашем случае — то что-то подобное тому, что предлагается в этом ответе.

Comment: @Euaek вы объекты пытаетесь по индексу в пустой список. Это в любом случае IndexError вызовет. Вместо этого нужно через append добавлять.

Comment: @insolor Точно, исправил.

Comment: @insolor : то есть inlinequery вывод после использования фрагмента кода выше должен выглядеть примерно так?: await bot.answer_inline_query(inline_query.id, [for i in range 5: items[i-1]]) если элементы из других списков в списки вкладывать не получится, то мне придется переписывать библиотеку?

Comment: @insolor, все, уже не нужно отвечать, все работает. спасибо

Comment: @max Удачи!))))

Comment: @Euaek благо дарю

Comment: _**:))))))))**_