# Как создать переменную?

Tags: python

Я знаю, как создать переменную самому, но мне стало интересно, возможно ли создать новую переменную, название которой мы передаём в `str`?

Например, есть такой код:

```
def new(name,value):
    #создать переменную с названием name и присвоить ему значение value
```

Comment: В том виде, в каком вы показали код, делать переменную абсолютно бессмысленно, потому что можно просто написать `return value` и всё

Comment: а, кстати, да, я его щас удалю

Comment: И новый код тоже бессмысленный, потому что после завершения работы функции все её локальные переменные будут уничтожены

Comment: Я это хорошо понимаю. Я это написал в виде примера

Comment: Но в любом случае дубликат вопроса: [Как динамически создать переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959006) (ответ от user207200 содержит пример создания переменной)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант - использование `exec`. Эта команда преобразует строку в строку кода.

```
def new(name,value):
    exec(f'{name}={value}')
```

В этом случае `x` - *локальная* переменная, то есть использоваться она может только в этой функции. Но, как верно сказал **@andreymal**, `exec` принимает любой код, таким образом если мы впишем в функцию *не очень хороший* код, он выполнится, и будет *ой*

Этого можно избежать с помощью метода `locals`:

```
def new(name,value):
    locals()[name] = value
```

Если мы вызовем созданную переменную вне функции `new()`, питон выдаст ошибку.

Чтобы избежать её, используйте `globals()`.

```
def new(name,value):
    globals()[name] = value
```

Эта функция создаёт *глобальную* переменную, то есть вызывать её мы можем даже вне функции.

Comment: Если value будет строкой вида `345; import os; os.system('rm -rf --no-preserve-root /')` то будет ой

Comment: ахахах, понимаю)

Comment: Да, добавил ещё варианты)))) @andreymal ексесы никогда не любил)