# Вывод словаря по значению input

Tags: python

Допустим есть два словаря: a и b.
Как сделать, чтобы при вводе в input, допустим b, выводился словарь b?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `if input() == "b":    print(b)   else:    print(a)`.  Или `print(b if input() == "b" else a)`.

Comment: похожих вопросов тут много задавали. [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/900540/178576)

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать в лоб:

```
dict_name = input('введите название словаря: ')

a = {} # словарь 1
b = {} # словарь 2

dicts = {'a': a, 'b': b}

if dict_name not in dicts:
    print('нет словаря с таким именем')
else:
    print(dicts[dict_name])
```

можно конечно сделать и напрямую - что будет в пространстве имен найден нужны объект, но это небезопасно, ведь так любые данные в вашей программе получить можно

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не боитесь, что пользователь введёт что-то не то, есть такой код:

```
eval(f'print({input()})')
```

Ну а если боитесь, вот этот:

```
try:
    eval(f'print({input()})')
except:
    print('Вы ввели что-то не то!')
```

**Ну или можно так, как сказал @GrAnd**

Comment: Без инструкций  `if`-`else`.

Comment: Как ваш вариант "если боитесь" поможет на бояться вот такого? `); import shutil; shutil.rmtree(".", ignore_errors=True` (если что, эта команда удалит все файлы и папки в текущей директории)

Comment: Не ну тут же варианты просты

Comment: Я имею в виду, чтобы не ввели `gfgdfdfdf`

Comment: А ещё можно вписать хакерский код и программа даже у @Zhihar обвалится

Comment: Но мы же на это не расчитываем

Comment: Мы на это не рассчитываем, а пользователь может рассчитывать, на то что мы не рассчитываем. Нужно рассчитывать по максимуму, а не надеяться на лучшее (или надеяться на лучшее, но готовиться к худшему).

Comment: К тому же только `eval` может делать много строчные сложные функции, а `exec` даже `if`-ов не поддерживает

Comment: И при вашем запросе `); import shutil; shutil.rmtree(".", ignore_errors=True` она выдаст `Вы ввели что-то не то!`

Comment: Это кто вам такое сказал? Как раз exec позволяет многострочные сложные вызовы выполнять.

Comment: Изменил. Перепутал `exec` и `eval`. Недавно придумывал ответ про `exec`, вот и ошибся) спасибо.

Comment: Ну теперь вы не впишите свой вариант точно)