# Как сделать переменную в имени которой будет число введенное пользователем с клавиатуры

Tags: python

Допустим у меня есть цикл

```py
for i in range (0, 4): 
   ...
```

и я хочу что бы у меня образовалось несколько переменных `player_`, в данном случае `player_0`, `player_1` и тд. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А зачем? Заведите для хранения значений список или словарь.

Comment: Потому что я смогу работать только с переменной в моем случае

Comment: Список или словарь и есть переменная. у списка уникальные индексы у словаря уникальные ключи

Comment: А что мешает работать с элементом списка или элементом словаря как с переменной?

Comment: потому что мне нужен динамические переменные которые бы создавались в зависимости от введенных данных. Например я пишу сейчас код покера и мне нужно реализовать переменные для каждого игрока но их должно создаваться столько сколько я запишу как пользователь

Comment: Вот как раз для таких случаев изобрели списки и словари. И вообще структуры данных. Вам предлагается наиболее простой и правильный вариант, но вы почему-то упорно от него отказываетесь. Какая вам, к примеру, разница, если вы будете обращаться к переменной как `player_0` или как `player[0]`?

Comment: а точнее я даже не правильно сформулировал мне нужно менять имя не переменной а списка)

Comment: А списки или словари чем не динамические переменные?

Comment: И даже если это переменная список, ничто не мешает её хранить в другом списке или как элемент словаря. Опять же - не вижу никакого смысла выносить что-либо в отдельные переменные. Потом будет обратный вопрос - "у меня есть 4 разных переменных, как по ним пройтись в цикле". Зачем усложнять себе жизнь?

Comment: ух ты, аж интересно стало. Где мой попкорн?

Comment: @ВладиславГуськов Интересно что такое "менять имя списка, а не переменной". Список - это точно такая же переменная, только содержит не одно значение, а собственно список. И никто не мешает положить список внутрь другого списка и будете спокойно обращаться к первому элементу списка для игрока 0 как `player[0][1]`

Comment: @GrAnd очевидные вещи для всех, но не для новичка

Comment: @ВладиславГуськов У вас очевидная проблема молотка https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710  лучше опишите изначальную задачу и спросите как лучше ее решать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как динамически создать переменную, в названии которой может содержаться значение другой переменной?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959006/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd

Comment: другой дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/900540/178576

Answer (score 0):

Да, так можно сделать с помощью функции `exec()` и `f-string` но к этой переменной вы не сможете непосредственно обратиться.

Выглядит это так:

```
for i in range(4):
    exec(f'player_{i}={some_value}')
```

Но я крайне не рекомендую так делать! Пустая трата времени, сам через такое проходил, знаю.

Вот лучший способ:

создаем `dict-comprenshion`

```
players = {f'player_{i}': some_value for i in range(4)}
```

получаем значение игрока

```
player = players.get('palayer_1')
```

Comment: т.к. `player_` присутствует во всех ключах словаря, то можно просто его убрать. в итоге останутся числа от 0 до 4, и вместо словооря можно будет использовать список

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться locals()

```
for i in range(5):
    locals()[f"player_{i}"] = i

print(player_1)
```